# Plot class probabilities using matplolitb

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have two numpy arrays `y_prob` and `dataY` whose values correspond. `dataY` is a one dimensional array where each value is a `1` or a `0`. `y_prob` is a two dimensional array. I wish to plot a scatter plot using `y_prob` to determine the location and `dataY` to determine the color of the point. How can I do this?
Sample data:

```
y_prob = [[0.5,0.5], [0.3,0.7], [0.2,0.8], [0.1,0.9]]
dataY = [1,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard packages `numpy` & `matplotlib`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_prob = np.array([[0.5,0.5], [0.3,0.7], [0.2,0.8], [0.1,0.9]])
dataY = [1,0,0,0]

fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x=y_prob[:,0], y=y_prob[:,1], c=dataY)
fig.show()
```